# ZCML configuration conflict between Zope2 and another zope.* package

Tags: plone, setuptools, zope, buildout, zcml

I have a Plone add-on with the following setup.py

```py
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        ...
        'zope.i18n',
        ...
        'Zope2',
    ],
    ...
)
```

If I run `bin/instance` I get the following traceback:

```
  File ".buildout/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 1527, in resolveConflicts
    raise ConfigurationConflictError(conflicts)
zope.configuration.config.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions
  For: ('utility', <InterfaceClass zope.i18n.interfaces.INegotiator>, '')
    File ".buildout/eggs/zope.i18n-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/i18n/configure.zcml", line 3.2-6.8
        <utility
            provides="zope.i18n.interfaces.INegotiator"
            component="zope.i18n.negotiator.negotiator"
            />
    File ".buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/ZPublisher/i18n.zcml", line 5.2-8.8
        <utility 
            provides="zope.i18n.interfaces.INegotiator"
            component="zope.i18n.negotiator.negotiator"
            />
```

If I comment out `zope.i18n` from `setup.py`, run buildout again, then the instance starts fine.

Surprisingly enough, both `bin/instance` files (before and after removing `zope.i18n`) are **exactly** the same.

So I'm sort of left clueless about what's wrong on defining something on `setup.py` that anyway the same version gets picked...

Last note, on the distribution's main `configure.zcml` I have this line:

```xml
<includeDependencies package="." />
```

Does this matter at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems odd?? obviously it's not possible to registry twice the same utility, but both packages do? I'm very confused about that. Usually you don't need the `<includeDependencies package="." />` parts, since all components should be loaded by the plone entry point of `z3c.autoinclude`. I assume in a default plone environment, one of the components will not be loaded.

I checked in on a Plone 4.3.6... The Negotiator of zope.i18n is used.

So my best bet is, that your `<includeDependencies package="." />`, also loads the configure.zcml of Zope2, which should not happen.

Removing the `<includeDependencies package="." />`, may solve your issue.

Comment: Yes! seems to be it, although it does not play well if you have some grok lying around... (I still haven't get rid completely of it)

Comment: Get rid of by using the https://github.com/collective/collective.z3cinspector - it helps a lot discovering,which component is registered and used (also in which package, etc.)